# Interpretation of color histogram

Tags: image-processing

I'm reading a paper about image processing and came across this color histogram:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bds4q.jpg). But I'm not sure how to interpet it. The 3 different curves are for red, green and blue. But what is on the X and Y-axis? My guess would be X-axis going from 0 to 255 for the 'intensity' of the color and Y-axis the amount of pixels in the image that have this intensity. Could anyone confirm this or correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Not an expert here but your interpretation sounds about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I know well, someone please correct me if I am wrong, the X axis represents the possible values of a color from either one of the RGB channels (a value in the [0-255] interval), and the Y axis represents the number of pixels having that value.

Comment: This corresponds perfectly with the interpretation that is given of this histogram. Thanks.

Comment: And the counts are normalized for the peak in this particular histogram: the peaks are made the same, even though the actual peak counts of pixels may differ by quite a bit. Otherwise, the pixel count scales would be same for all colors, and the peaks would not appear at same height usually.